# Where can I find an updated driver for my display (NVIDIA Geforce 7150M)

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, windows-vista

Where can I find an updated driver for my display that is a NVIDIA Geforce 7150M for Windows Vista 32-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [nvidia's download page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us)?

Comment: Yes, I have driver of version 179.44. It is latest according to them.

Comment: You could also try here: http://www.laptopvideo2go.com/drivers

Answer (score 1):

You don't say why you need an updated driver, or what's wrong with the current one.  Consequently, I can only give you information about why you're probably not going to find much of anything.

The GeForce 7150M is an embedded model of graphics adapter.  That is, PC manufacturers (HP, Dell, Toshiba, Acer, et al) buy the chipset from nVidia to install on the system board for their laptops or commodity desktops.  However, laptop devices are different than desktop devices, because the systems need to be able to gracefully handle all the power events that happen on a laptop (move to battery, move to A/C power, standyby, display brightness, primary/secondary output switching, etc.).  Consequently, PC makers need to use the device to be able to communicate with the display in ways that the chipset maker (nVidia) doesn't control.  PC makers get an SDK so that they can develop their own driver packages which support these additional features.

Now you're faced with an interesting problem.  PC makers only support a given model for a fraction of the time that nVidia supports a line of chipsets, and PC makers have a fraction of the staff to do the supporting.  Therefore, unless a driver package has bugs or significant problems, PC makers generally do not release multiple versions of drivers.  You get one version at the time the laptop model is released, and (sometimes) another version at the time the laptop reaches the end of it's support life.  That's all.  However, the driver from your PC manufacturer is the most likely driver to be stable, and is the only driver they're going to support.  You don't list the make or model of your computer, however, so I can't help you there.

Usually, you cannot install drivers from nVidia for these types of installations because they lack the specialized software for managing the display which the PC makers create.  You'll notice the [179.48 driver on nVidia's site](http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_notebook_winvista_win7_179.48_beta.html) for this model of adapter (the only driver they list) is marked as a Beta.  It's marked as a Beta because it's just a reference driver.  It's likely to be unstable because it the software from your PC manufacturer isn't present.  It says as much at the top of the release highlights.

You could also try the [latest release for the 7xxx series](http://www.nvidia.com/object/win7-winvista-32bit-275.33-whql-driver.html), but I suspect the installer will complain that your specific device is supported by the PC manufacturer.

Your final chance would be to use the device driver from Microsoft, but in my experience those often fail spectacularly on embedded display adapters.  You can either check on Windows Update, or you can remove the drivers and force it to look on Microsoft's site.  Uninstall all driver packages for the display adapter.  Then uninstall the display device itself and reboot.  When Windows looks for the display driver, tell it to look online.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Now that laptop 's GPU is burnt, it also damaged the motherboard, so I have scrapped that laptop. ;)